# what wrong with !IsPostBack?

Tags: c#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
if(!IsPostBack)
{
LoadQuestion(); //randomly choose question from database and put inside panel1
LoadQuestion1();//randomly choose question from database and put inside panel2
Panel1.visible=true;
Panel2.visible=false;
}

void LoadQuestion()
{
while (dtr.Read())
{
question[index, 0] = dtr["Question"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 1] = dtr["OptionA"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 2] = dtr["OptionB"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 3] = dtr["OptionC"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 4] = dtr["OptionD"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 5] = dtr["Answer"].ToString().Trim();
question[index, 6] = dtr["QuestionNo"].ToString().Trim();
index++;
}
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 Label lbl = new Label();
 RadioButtonList rad = new RadioButtonList();
 lbl.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
 rad.ID = "rad" + i.ToString();

 lbl.Text = i + ". " + question[num, 0].ToString();
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 1]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 2]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 3]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 4]);
 Panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
 Panel1.Controls.Add(rad);
}
}



void LoadQuestion1()
{

for(i=11;i<20;i++)
{
 Label lbl = new Label();
 RadioButtonList rad = new RadioButtonList();
 lbl.ID = "lbl" + i.ToString();
 rad.ID = "rad" + i.ToString();

 lbl.Text = i + ". " + question[num, 0].ToString();
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 1]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 2]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 3]);
 rad.Items.Add(question[i, 4]);
 Panel2.Controls.Add(lbl);
 Panel2.Controls.Add(rad);
}
}

protected void lb1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Panel1.Visible = true;
Panel2.Visible = false;
}

protected void lb2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Panel2.Visible = true;
Panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

in this case, if i didnt put `!IsPostBack` inside Page_Load, once i click on `lb1` or `lb2` , the questions will keep on changing.. 
after i put `!IsPostBack` inside `Page_Load`, once i click on `lb1` or `lb2` , the `Panel1` and `Panel2` become nothing... my page become totally blank... what's going wrong???

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get more answers to your question, I recommend that you create a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/). Your example is not yet short (everything that is not required to reproduce the error should be removed), it's not yet self-contained (the aspx page is missing), it's not yet compilable (for example, Page_Load misses a closing brace).,

Answer (score 0):

Because you are adding the controls to the Panels inside your LoadQuestion function. When the page reloads, the Panels will be created but the Labels and RadioButton lists will not.

To have this functionality, every time through Page_Load, you need to recreate the controls in the panels but then you either need to reload the questions from the database or store them somewhere, like in the ViewState or Session and use these to re-populate the radiobutton list..

Comment: can viewstate to store 2D array?? because i need to store the question as well as the Option A to D into viewstate in order to retrieve value and put into radio button list

Answer (score 0):

With out being able to compile your code I am just haszording a guess here but since `IsPostBack` looks to see if there the current request is NOT a post back (I.E. the first page load) it will not execute

`LoadQuestion(); //randomly choose question from database and put inside panel1
LoadQuestion1();//randomly choose question from database and put inside panel2
Panel1.visible=true;
Panel2.visible=false;`

You will need to move one of the panels to be in a `PostBack` load so It will show.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case not putting !IsPostBack in the load method calls loadQuestion when the page is first loaded and anything that triggers a postback. In the second case adding !IsPostback to the load method only calls loadQuestion on the initial load never on postback which is what your click events cause. Lastly the controls are being added dynamically during load and these will not exist through postback. Consider using AJAX http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx

Comment: in general preventing full page postbacks is a good idea especially in those cases where the state of the page is not preserved. look at the asp.net ajax update panel.